# Dataframe group based on one column and get the sum of value of desired items for another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently my dataframe is:

```
dd = [[1001,'green apple',1,7],[1001,'red apple',1,2],[1001,'grapes',1,5],[1002,'green apple',2,4],[1002,'red apple',2,4],[1003,'red apple',3,8],[1004,'mango',4,2],[1004,'red apple',4,6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(dd, columns = ['colID','colString','custID','colQuantity'])
```

```
   colID     colString     custID     colQuantity 
0   1001    green apple     1            7
1   1001    red apple       1            2
2   1001    grapes          1            5
3   1002    green apple     2            4
4   1002    red apple       2            4
5   1003    red apple       3            8
6   1004    mango           4            2
7   1004    red apple       4            6
```

Right now I only managed to filter rows that contains red and green apple using the code:

```
selection = ['green apple','red apple']
mask = df.colString.apply(lambda x: any(item for item in selection if item in x))
df = df[mask]
```

Current Output:

```
   colID     colString     custID     colQuantity 
0   1001    green apple     1            7
1   1001    red apple       1            2
3   1002    green apple     2            4
4   1002    red apple       2            4
5   1003    red apple       3            8
7   1004    red apple       4            6
```

The final desired output is getting the sum of green apple AND red apple that has the same colID:

```
   colID   custID colQuantity
   1001      1        9
   1002      2        8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to index the dataframe and then [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
(df[df.colString.isin(['green apple', 'red apple'])]
   .groupby(['colID','colString'], as_index=False)
   .sum())

    colID   colString  colQuantity
0   1001  green apple            7
1   1001    red apple            2
2   1002  green apple            4
3   1002    red apple            4
4   1003    red apple            8
5   1004    red apple            6
```

Comment: Is it possible to sum both of green and red apple? Only sum if there's green and red apple having the same colID